# draw lines like electricity from objects origins, across particles in a volumetric material to other object?

Tags: particles, smoke-simulation, volumetrics

How would I draw lines connecting object to other objects using particles to simulate lighting inside a volume? I want to use it in a fire sim like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5s6VN1-ukqU&feature=youtu.be).

Comment: Can post a picture of what kind of effect you are looking for?

Comment: If you want to create effect of lightning strikes, proobably the best way could be to actually model those "lines"

Comment: this is to be procedural, and arc from a point to another point, In bge I would label the targets with a property but I have very little bpy experience. The first thing I intend to use it for, is to have minnor 'zaps'into the air targeting to a second particle system, to make a ball lighting type effect...

Comment: I have been thinking about it, and I need to use the point on line mathutils to get a vector, and apply a force to push particles into a line, and also apply turbulence, and somehow ensure there are more particles on the 'start' side then the 'end' side.

Then I will use fire sim + particles to 'draw' the lighting,

but yeah, point on line force between two points..... I can't do that in BPY can I?